# Does the return statement work from inner to outter?

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with the return statement in javascript.  Here is [msdn definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22a685h9%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Here is a function I wrote that converts a binary number to a decimal number:

```
function bin2dec(num){
    **return** num.toString().split('').reverse().reduce(function(preVal, currentVal , iterator){
        **return** (currentVal === '1') ? preVal + Math.pow(2, iterator) : preVal;
    }, 0);
  }
```

Let's use the 5 in binary as an example to work with Binary5 = 101

So I thought whenever you use a return statement, it exits the current function prematurely.

Here I have two return statements, one within a callback function.

The first return statement is on the second line:

```
return num.toString().split('').reverse() // and then the reduce function w/ a call back.
```

I believe this 'return' statement is waiting for the reduce function's return

The function takes the number, makes it a string, then splits, then reverses, then the reduce method iteates over the array. When the reduce function is complete it returns a value which is then also returned by the first return value. Here is more detail about the reduce functions return value.

In the callback:

```
// 101
    .reduce(function(preVal, currentVal , iterator){
            return (currentVal === '1') ? preVal + Math.pow(2, iterator) : preVal;
        }, 0);
```

It iterates over each part of the array, in this case the 'return' is preVal unless the
currentVal === 1.  The 'return' value is passed to the callback and is the value of preVal. for each loop we are adding and building on the current val from the pre val. When every item in the array is iterated on, the return statement is the final value. That final value is then returned from the 1st return statement that did not execute yet.

I really get lost with return statements at times.  I am mainly trying to check if my logic in how the 'return' statements are acting the way I am describing. For a quick recap

1. First Return - waits for everything to be evaluated so there is an
   object to return.
2. Second Return - is used for the callback and when it is done
       iterating, the last return value is returned, then that value is
       acted on from the first return statement that ultimately breaks out
       of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see [how the `return` statement is defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9)

```
return [no LineTerminator here] Expression ;
```

and it is evaluated as

> If *Expression* is omitted, the return value is `undefined`. Otherwise, the return value is the value of *Expression*.

You see, there is no word about *other* return statements. *Any* expression is valid in a return statement and it doesn't matter *what* the expression exactly is.

---

The follow up question is then what `num.toString().split('').reverse().reduce(...)` exactly is and how it is evaluated.

`num.toString().split('').reverse().reduce(...)` is a *call expression* and the result of this expression is the return value of the function.

So how does `reduce` work? `reduce` converts an array to a single value. It does that by executing a function for each element in the array and passing the return value of that function of the previous iteration to the next iteration.

---

So the bottom line is that the two `return` statements don't have anything to do with each other, they are completely independent. It might be easier to see if you define the function beforehand:

```
function bin2dec(num){
  function callback(preVal, currentVal , iterator){
    return (currentVal === '1') ? preVal + Math.pow(2, iterator) : preVal;
  }
  return num.toString().split('').reverse().reduce(callback, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find this functional style of programming difficult to grasp, then split it up into smaller parts. The following code is equivalent to yours:

```
function bin2dec(num) {
    var decimal = num.toString().split('').reverse().reduce(addDigit, 0);
    return decimal;
}

function addDigit(preVal, currentVal, iterator) {
    return (currentVal === '1') ? preVal + Math.pow(2, iterator) : preVal;
}
```

It also helps to think of 'return' as 'yields a value', rather than 'exits from a block of code'.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I am trying to get a clear understanding of implementing it the way I did.  I actually had your current code in my first try but wanted to try and condense it into one function.  I was somewhat guessing when inserting return statements to get my current version to work.  I think my logic on how the two returns statements are working is correct but am just trying to double check  I am thinking correctly.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Both your code and your understanding are fine. It is alright to use anonymous functions like you did; as long as you keep the inner function small, it should not hurt readability.